# Troubleshooting Wordpress Pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

i'm currently trying to get the Pagination in my Wordpress System working but as it seems it's always failing because of some weird issues with the WP_Query property which returns 0 for max_num_pages as soon as the global property is used.

For the query, which I used to get the posts I need, the max_num_pages property is set properly.
This is the query I use to fetch the Posts:

```
return new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'dokumente',
            'post__in' => $documentIds,
            'no_found_rows'          => true,
            'posts_per_page'         => 10,
        ));
```

And this is the code I try to use for rendering the Page:

```
if ($documentQuery->have_posts()) {
while ($documentQuery->have_posts()) : $documentQuery->the_post();
    global $wp_query;
    global $post;
    $document = $post;
    
endwhile;
?>
<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('Older posts'); ?></div>


<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer posts'); ?></div>
<?php
```

}

The query is passed to a function as '$documentQuery'.

Would be nice if someone could help me here. I'm stuck on this since a day, now.

Comment: What is `global $wp_query;` doing there in the first place? That's not even the query you are looping over there, that would be `$documentQuery`.

Comment: You should probably simply pass `$documentQuery->max_num_pages` as second parameter to `next_posts_link`.

Comment: @CBroe yes, that's the way I solved it, now. Thanks for the hint! Didn't know that that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @CBroe I'm now passing `$documentQuery->max_num_pages` as second parameter to the `next_posts_link`.
For all the generic functions that relied on the `global $wp_query` property, I've replaced that with my `$documentQuery` before calling the functions that relied on `$wp_query`.